# Transform Array of objects of objects into new array of objects in tabular form

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, object, array.prototype.map

Given the sample data, I need to transform whats given and return in tabular form. Here is the sample data. How can I get the output to be what it is below?

```
var revisions = {
data:[
    // row 1
    {
      cId: {
        value: "123456",
        oldValue: null
      },
      revisionDate:{
        value: "09/01/2021",
        oldValue: "09/21/2021"
      },
      revisionType:{
        value: "UPDATE",
        oldValue: "DELETE"
      },
      revisionNote:{
        value: "Some test note 0",
        oldValue: "Old revision note 0"
      },
      financeNo:{
        value: "FA1",
        oldValue: "FA2"
      }
    },
    // row 2
    {
      dccId: {
        value: "123457",
        oldValue: null
      },
      revisionDate:{
        value: "05/01/2021",
        oldValue: "09/28/2021"
      },
      revisionType:{
        value: "NEW",
        oldValue: "UPDATE"
      },
      revisionNote:{
        value: "Some test note 1",
        oldValue: "Old revision note 1"
      },
      financeNo:{
        value: "FA4",
        oldValue: "FA5"
      },
      maintNo:{
        value: "MN001",
        oldValue: "MN002"
      },
      isSpare:{
        value: 0,
        oldValue: 1
      }
    },
    // row 3 ...
  ]
}
```

The console output should be:

```
[
  {cId: "123456", revisionDateNew: "09/01/2021", revisionDateOld:"09/21/2021", revisionTypeNew: "UPDATE",revisionTypeOld: "DELETE", revisionNoteNew: "Some test note 0", revisionNoteOld: "Old revision note 0", financeNoNew: "FA1", financeNoOld: "FA2", maintNoNew: "",      maintNoOld: "",      isSpareNew: "",  isSpareOld: ""},
  {cId: "123457", revisionDateNew: "05/01/2021", revisionDateOld:"09/28/2021", revisionTypeNew: "NEW",   revisionTypeOld: "UPDATE", revisionNoteNew: "Some test note 1", revisionNoteOld: "Old revision note 1", financeNoNew: "FA4", financeNoOld: "FA5", maintNoNew: "MN001", maintNoOld: "MN002", isSpareNew: "0", isSpareOld: "1"}, 
  ...
]
```

So far this is what Ive done but Im stuck on how to not hard code the properties and Im also struggling to figure out the logic needed to assign a 'New' and 'Old' to the current properties and then give those the correct values.

```
function loopData(revisions: any) {
  var newData = revisions.data.map(item => ({
    cId: item.cId.value,
    revisionDateNew: item.revisionDate.value
  }))
  console.log(newData)
}
```

I think what I need is another loop maybe a forEach where I get the keys and then create a new array to push the new fields.

Comment: can you write a function that takes an object of your old representation and creates a corresponding object unwrapping the `value` field? You could just pass that function to the `revisions.data.map` function to get the whole thing done

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to do that

Comment: clarification, how much type safety did you want on the solution? you tagged the question with typescript but trying to do it now I'm having a heck of a time getting any kind of types to work properly

Comment: You'd want something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzJAJgHgCoD4oF4oDeAbggDYCuEAXFBgDRQD2pKAamZQPw0ZQA+UAHblSpAL4BYAFChIsRGACCogNIQQAZ0w58BANoqoAS0FQA1usYAzWgF0a8JKkwHbWSVOlXyggMbAjRlMfAHcFAH0SUi1sAAoUBGAEBwVlUjVNbQBKHgJpKChfII1gKDgIDRFgGgAFBDgAsm08Qg8Cq0Y4KFiiwRKoPTM6IlsmGwB5ACMAKwh-ADoIQWA4Iwr4xIQsrLypAoLyytJgQagEDXNLGwxR-FiiM4vHZAh0DEGruyws+ajKAG58lA2mUIMByHBTIcqo9aNIPL1+oIICEACKbFrlIhGDSBPrzBJJeYAWyQsVCESiGiyQA) but making it preserve the right type just from the data declaration is... hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general function I've used a lot `objectMap` to map each field in an object to some other data:

```
/**
 * similar to Array.map but for the fields of an object.
 * the callback takes the value as first argument and key as second.
 * does not support passing object as 3rd argument or thisArg.
 */
export function objectMap<T, V>(obj: T, fn: (val: T[keyof T], key: keyof T) => V) {
    // this is one of the cases where the as Record followed by a loop initializing all the keys
    // the whole reason this function exists is to have this typesafe outside :)
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
    const newObj = {} as Record<keyof T, V>;
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        newObj[key as keyof T] = fn(val, key as keyof T);
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

With this you can get the correct data structure with this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhnAlgW0QGwIYCdoBcD20AgllhgJ4B0yGADtAEYCuu0AZvjrgBYCm7iXmgAm8aPjbQMAO3EMAVrwDGuSlFh4+0JRjRoGGJQGs8GI7zE9+AN11N+GMW0RZ4rbAHMmyXtPfThaHNyKTF4ZXwAtRg4YXwLaGl8VngmWlpOVlpHJGkPOUUVUOgAZixAz29fVk5NRHgSD2jYYCg2JmkVREiC5VwAWToAHgAVABpoADUAPgAKfAUALmhx9mll2ds0ZZGAbWCJFYBdCeDlg8kRgEpoAF5pqZuAb3VoN+BgOrF68Wl+Q6s2kcCQA7nwsPxAY5oAAlCLldj4PT4EG8QIMEIYaBofD4eiIaSIXCIXSIABeBPyujQmn4wXgr3en0BYKR-Ahjh6PB+7U6xJ6vAAHvVcN9LIRuBhrJDuD9cORaBYMGx-iwkMJ+IsrozoB9oBY0ATcABaYT1DAMNC8Y1-QUmw1-aAAAXlivgSiwiFoJoNRuASkiSDc1WNrutOV4WH50gZMDe2kDrD+IIA8go7tAngBfYpwgPlIYXFYTGYAbh1HBwswDMdY+145AmWyO4kkacKqmqnos8wUV2eOvjiV4qYU9cxYiLIxbtzWm10pwbxSnV3LcbeWZ1ENwTCwsmT7bXm8gthwEOs9W6MYzL0gwgwuAwi12Or1WBR0AAjDrb0O3koAElhGWX8-zeLZ7GWAAiT8ACYSgAFgAVgANigsZB3jJFhEmOxeGWaQmD0TCsww9d43PS9IgAEQffDQLAiD8OgKCAAYAE5gFYz9gFg1jYM-dDMLebDcLQSCWI43ieL4gSoJIsiwMopBIhGBV6OE6AmOggBVAAFaiiBGABRITyKHUS8Og6jjIAGWMkz5PM6BSMw5SrwAOWSDTnPAqyWIAZXwHw8AsJNvOgVizLAkSRDEiSoJTERoHcnoklwfgooUzDnGkGQlF4LzFgYv9tJYgAxIhBMUmLLPE5ioMq2CnLA48h1c8i3w-WCf0w4QlEA4DM00sqYPg5CAHZotquL-MI4jnI6pTeAvFTpFojLipG-y2KQriZP46rNLqhKpNggAOXjDpav8lr-VLpDUxUtt8rSdo84yAHVprAk6Gv0wzHOy5yHq8zaSqHUagpCjK3ESCKjtev7oKSwIHvhjKvxu9qaqHXL8sK-AXpit76ugyqEJ+v9kYqogkOx+M7qHGgjSKiH41G-oPNY7iqYs2ayZYrmeea4GwPqALsghYmYrK1jcepgWJO-RadSZ3VPnfEFSmgSg9deI4oBzaEazcKBTaTEcNqxWcHvgSh70fag6E2e4Fg7QZaE2CZBXuQUAH5KCY-sgA)

```
const newData = revisions.data.map(v=>objectMap(v, x=>x?.value))
```

Note that it doesn't preserve the types completely as we'd need [this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22617) to type this properly in general, you will likely want an interface to denote the type of the output anyway so this probably isn't a problem for you.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you.